# Why does this particular ratio of prime numbers seems to converge to 3?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, experimental-mathematics

I noticed this interesting property of prime numbers, and I'd like to know if it has an explanation/proof/disproof.

Define $p(n)$ to be the $n$'th prime number.

Define the following sequence: 
 $$\Sigma(n) =
\begin{cases}
p(1),  & \text{if $n=1$} \\
\Sigma(n-1)+p(n), & \text{if $n>1$ and  $\Sigma(n-1)-p(n)<0$} \\
\Sigma(n-1)-p(n), & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The first few elements of the sequence are:  $2,5,0,7,18,5,22,3,26,55$.

Now, in $\Sigma(n)$ lets look at all indexes $n$'s such that $\Sigma(n-1)<\Sigma(n)<\Sigma(n+1)$. These indexes also form a sequence, which I'll denote by $a(k)$. Here are its first elements: $4,9,22,57,146,367,946,2507$.

So, what I noticed is that these two limits seem to hold: 
$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{p(a(k+1))}{p(a(k))} = 3$$
$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{\Sigma(a(k+1))}{\Sigma(a(k))} = 3$$

Here is a graph of the former of these ratios:
[image: graph of ratio sequence]

Of course, these are only empirical findings. Do you have other reasons to believe that they are true?

Comment: What was your motivation for looking at these particular functions and ratios?

Comment: No motivation, just playing around (It was actually about 10 years ago, when I was 18. And now I just stumbled upon this again. See also https://oeis.org/A135025)

Comment: Prime numbers are ugly (or call them beautiful, if you like - that doesn't matter) in that any asymptotical statements like this are god-awfully difficult to prove. I tried the same construction with sums of $\pm n$ instead of $\pm p_n$, and got (or so it seems) the limit of 3 as well! I tried $n^2$, and got $\sqrt3$. Now that's something to think about...

Comment: Look at http://oeis.org/A008344, that's partial sums with $\pm n$. They seem to have an explanation for the $3^n$ asymptotics (not that it extends nicely to $\pm p_n$, though).

Comment: @IvanNeretin when I use $n^2$ instead of $p_n$, I actually get $3$ again. The $\sqrt{3}$ is the ratio of the $a$ sequence.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, I looked at the ratios of $a_n$. So thinking of ratios of $\Sigma(a)$, 3 seems to be some kind of universal constant.

Comment: $3$ seems universal also when I take powers of $p_n$, such as $p_n^2$. Although for geometrically increasing sequence I just get the ratio of the sequence.

Comment: I've not proven your claim, but I have proven that $\Sigma$ can increase just one or two times in a row and that it never decreases twice in a row. Would you like me to post the proof?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I got the *idea* of where the universal constant 3 comes from, but not the proof for $p_n$.

Let $d_n$ be a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers, such that the differences $d_{n+1}-d_n$ are asymptotically "small" compared to $d_n$ themselves. Let's form a series of partial sums of $\pm d_n$ according to the same rules: minus unless this would drive the sum into the negatives, otherwise plus. (On a side note, I don't like the idea of non-standard usage of $\Sigma$, but also I don't like to introduce extra symbols unless absolutely necessary, so I will just avoid mentioning these partial sums other than verbally). Now what does it *mean* when a partial sum has two growth steps in a row?

Most of the time, the signs just follow a dull alternating sequence: +, -, +, -, +, -... Every once in a while, the partial sum drops so low that the next  (+, -) would drive it below 0 (which means that the sum was *really* low, less than $d_{n+1}-d_n$, which itself is $o(d_n)$, like I said before). Then we throw in an extra plus (so the sum which was basically $0$ becomes basically $d_n$), and then continue with the dull +, -, +, -, +, -... BTW, that's when $n$ becomes the next term in the $a_k$ series. Now, each (+, -) brings the sum a little lower, because $d_i-d_{i+1}<0$. How long it might be before these bites deplete our stock and the sum is driven close to 0 again? If we would add **every** difference, they would all telescope nicely, and we'd have $d_{next}-d_n\approx d_n$, or $d_{next}\approx 2d_n$. But we use just **every other** difference. Now, if the sequence grows relatively "uniformly" (which is easy to prove for $d_n=n$ or $n^2$, but not easy at all for $d_n=p_n$), then the sum of every other difference is about half of sum of all differences, so it boils down to ${1\over2}(d_{next}-d_n)\approx d_n$, or $d_{next}\approx \color{red}{\bf3}d_n$.

Comment: I couldn't follow this explanation. What do you mean by adding every other difference?

Comment: Adding, did I say? "Subtracting" might be the right word, but... Whatever. See, we just added $d_n$ (that extra plus), and start depleting it by adding $d_{n+1}-d_{n+2}$, which is the same as subtracting $d_{n+2}-d_{n+1}$, and so on. How do we estimate the sum of these subtracted pieces? If it were the series of **all** differences, like $(d_{n+2}-d_{n+1})+(d_{n+3}-d_{n+2})+(d_{n+4}-d_{n+3})+(d_{n+5}-d_{n+4})+...$, then it would telescope and everything. But we don't have all differences. We have only half of them, namely $(d_{n+2}-d_{n+1})+(d_{n+4}-d_{n+3})+(d_{n+6}-d_{n+5})+...$ So it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Say for some $n$:
$$\Sigma(n-1)<\Sigma(n)<\Sigma(n+1)$$
Then: 
$$\Sigma(n+1)=\Sigma(n-1)+p(n)+p(n+1)\geq p(n)+p(n+1)$$
Suppose $n>25$. Now $p(n)>\dfrac{5}{6}p(n+1)$ and $p(n+2)<\frac65p(n+1)<\frac{36}{25}p(n)$. Hence:
$$p(n)+p(n+1)>\Big(\frac56+1\Big)p(n)>\frac{36}{25}p(n)>p(n+2)$$
So $\Sigma(n+1)>p(n+2).$ Therefore $\Sigma(n)$ cannot increase more than $2$ times in a row for $n>25$.

---

Say for some $n$:
$$\Sigma(n-1)>\Sigma(n)>\Sigma(n+1)$$
Then:
$$\Sigma(n-1)\geq p(n)+p(n+1)>p(n-1)+p(n)$$
Therefore $\Sigma(n-2)>p(n-1)$ and $\Sigma(n-1)=\Sigma(n-2)-p(n-1)$. So:
$$\Sigma(n-1)>\Sigma(n)>\Sigma(n+1)\implies \Sigma(n-2)>\Sigma(n-1)>\Sigma(n)$$
But since $\Sigma(n)$ decreases somewhere (For instance, $\Sigma(3)<\Sigma(2)$), there are not $n$ such that $\Sigma(n-1)>\Sigma(n)>\Sigma(n+1)$ and hence $\Sigma$ does never decrease twice in a row.

---

This confirms what Ivan Neretin says, namely that the pattern will be +,-+,-... and occasionally +,+,-, when $\Sigma(n-1)<p(n+1)-p(n)$.